# Adding multiple must_not in elasticquery

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

I want to achieve following:

1. LogMessage should n't contain `too many connection`.
2. LogMessage must present.
3. LogMessage mustn't `contain no conn`.

The must not query is:

```
 "must_not" => [
                "regexp" =>[
                    "LogMessage" => ".*Too many connections.*"
                ]
              ],
              "must_not" => [
                "regexp" =>[
                    "LogMessage" => "^.{0,0}$"
                ]
              ],

               "must_not" => [
                "regexp" =>[
                    "LogMessage" => ".*no conn.*"
                ]
              ],
```

But the above is not working properly.

Comment: Try replacing `"^.{0,0}$"` with `".{0}"`. If it does not work, the problem is with the code logic.

Comment: Also, try a regex like `.+&~(.*(Too many connections|no conn).*)` with `must` logic.

Comment: Does the above satisfies my conditions?

Comment: Yes, but those are just regex fixes.  However, I am not sure as for query itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this instead:

```
   "must_not" => [
          [
            "regexp" =>[
                "LogMessage" => ".*Too many connections.*"
            ]
          ],
          [
            "regexp" =>[
                "LogMessage" => "^.{0,0}$"
            ]
          ],
          [
            "regexp" =>[
                "LogMessage" => ".*no conn.*"
            ]
          ]
   ]
```

Comment: this is also working: `"regexp" =>[
          "LogMessage" => ".*no conn.*|.*Too many connections.*|^.{0,0}$"
         ],`